# Преобразование типов float в double

Tags: c++, c, float, double, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

У меня есть код. Почему первый вывод printf() отличается от второго (хотя оба используют `sqrtf()`), но второй совпадает с третим выводом `printf()` (а он использует sqrt()), ведь `double y` получает значение типа `float`, а потом преобразовывает его в `double`, как оно может восстановить утерянные цифры и иметь тот же результат, что и `yy`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SQRT(X) _Generic((X),\
        default : sqrt,\
        float : sqrtf)(X)

int main(void)
{
  float m=sqrtf(45.0f);
  printf("%.17f\n",m);
  float x=45.0f;
  double xx=45.0;
  double y=SQRT(x);
  double yy=SQRT(xx);
  printf("%.17f\n", y);
  printf("%.17lf\n", yy);
  return 0;
}
```

Пример выдачи:

```
6.70820379257202150
6.70820393249936940
6.70820393249936940
```

Comment: Не воспроизводится.

Answer (score 5):

Согласно стандартам языков C и C++ вычисления над типами с плавающей точкой могут (но не обязаны!) производиться с большей точностью (precision) и диапазоном (range), чем требуют используемые для вычислений типы. Например, рассмотрим такой код (предполагаем что `float` — обычный 32-битный тип, удовлетворяющий требованиям стандарта IEEE 754):

```
float x, a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
...    //Присваиваем переменным a, b, c, d, e, f, g некоторые значения.
x = a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
```

С учётом ассоциативности бинарные операторы `+` должны выполнятся слева направо. Сперва находится сумма `a + b`, затем получившийся результат складывается с `c`, затем результат с предыдущего шага складывается с `d` и т.д. Каждый промежуточный результат в данном случае имеет тип `float`. Но при этом каждый промежуточный результат может иметь большую точность и диапазон, чем таковые у типа `float`!

Чем может быть обусловлено такое необычное поведение? Дело в том, что регистры процессора используемые для операций над числами с плавающей точкой могут быть больше, чем того требует используемый тип. Типичный пример — [модуль вычислений с плавающей точкой (floating point unit, FPU)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80) — имеет 80-битные регистры.

Чтобы каждый промежуточный результат в приведённом примере имел в точности тип `float` без всяких послаблений на диапазон и точность, необходимо приложить некоторые дополнительные усилия по конвертации 80-битного числа с плавающей точкой в 32-битное. Естественно, конвертация не бесплатна в плане производительности.

В целях повышения производительности, напрашивается идея о вычислении всех промежуточных результатов с повышенной точностью, и только в конце итоговую сумму преобразовывать в 32-битный `float`.  К сожалению, разные методы вычисления промежуточных результатов могут приводить к разным итоговым суммам.

Обычно на практике возможные различия в итоговом результате не важны. Поэтому компилятор выбирает ту стратегию вычисления промежуточных результатов, которая обеспечивает наибольшее быстродействие.

Также стоит отметить, что стандарты языков C и C++ требует при использовании явного приведения типа или оператора присваивания преобразовывать расширенную точность и диапазон до точности и диапазона типа к которому происходит приведение или присваивание.

```
double d1, d2;
float f;
d1 = ...; d2 = ...;
f = d1 + (float)d2;
```

В приведённом фрагменте кода перед вычислением суммы `d2` должен быть преобразован к типу `float`, и результат суммы также должен быть преобразован к типу `float`. Суммирование без предварительного преобразования `double` во `float` не допускается. Хоть результат суммирования и может иметь точность и диапазон большие чем у типа `double` (вспоминаем про 80-битные регистры), присваивание результата суммирования переменной `f` без предварительного преобразования в тип `float` не допускается.

На практике, следует быть осторожным, если вы полагаетесь на гарантии даваемые стандартом языка  на явное приведение типа и использование оператора присваивания. **Некоторые опции компилятора игнорируют данные гарантии.** Например, в Visual Studio при использовании опции `/fp:fast` округления при присваивании и приведении типа [могут быть опущены](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fp-specify-floating-point-behavior?view=vs-2019):

> The compiler may omit rounding at assignment statements, typecasts, or function calls.

[Судя по документации](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), GCC использует по-умолчанию опцию `-fexcess-precision=fast`. Эта опция также снимает гарантии относительно преобразований типов при приведении типов и присваивании:

> By default, `-fexcess-precision=fast` is in effect; this means that operations may be carried out in a wider precision than the types specified in the source if that would result in faster code, and it is unpredictable when rounding to the types specified in the source code takes place.

Теперь по поводу вашего кода. Стандарт языка не специфицирует конкретный способ вычисления значения, возвращаемого функцией `sqrtf`. Вероятно, в вашем случае компилятор воспользовался FPU для извлечения квадратного корня и получил 80-битный результат. В первом случае он преобразовал его в 32-битный `float`. Но во втором случае, компилятор счёл необходимым в целях повышения быстродействия не преобразовывать результат к "честному" `float`. Согласно документации, он имеет право так поступить, хотя конечный результат получается несколько неожиданным.

Упростим немного ваш код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    volatile float x = 45.0f;
    volatile double xx = 45.0;

    double y  = sqrtf(x);
    double yy = sqrt(xx);

    printf("%.17f\n", y);
    printf("%.17f\n", yy);

    return 0;
}
```

И скомпилируем его с использованием опции `-mfpmath=387`, чтобы вычисления производились в FPU. Вывод ([C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d5de383b3ff5558), [C](https://rextester.com/HKTY90893)):

```
6.70820393249936942
6.70820393249936942
```

Добавим опцию `-ffloat-store` для принудительного округления промежуточных результатов. Вывод ([C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31d70b38de929205), [C](https://rextester.com/LHSIN85304)):

```
6.70820379257202148
6.70820393249936942
```

---

Смотрите также баг 46080: [incorrect precision of sqrtf builtin for x87 arithmetic](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46080), который по своей сути эквивалентен изложенной в вашем вопросе проблеме. Баг закрыт со статусом RESOLVED INVALID — описанная проблема не является ошибкой.

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю как у вас, но у меня вот такой результат вышеизложенного кода

```
user% gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror stack.c
user% ./a.out
6.70820379257202148
6.70820379257202148
6.70820393249936942
user% gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

А вот результат вывода в `gcc 6.3`

```
6.70820379257202148
6.70820379257202148
6.70820393249936942
```

Скорее всего дело в вашем компиляторе. Подсказать, что нужно изменить я вам не смогу, так как не могу найти компилятор с таким же поведением (проверил дополнительно на 3 онлайн ресурсах). Буду рад, если вы дополнительно укажете IDE, которым пользуетесь для дальнейшего решения вопроса.

Comment: Вот у вас как раз результат такой, какой я ожидаю увидеть и у себя... Я пользуюсь codeblocks

Comment: Смените в настройках компилятор на другой, например на GNU GCC Compiler, и проверьте еще раз.

Comment: он у меня и стоит))

Comment: может более древняя версия стоит) я проверял на новой и на 6.3, за более ранние не ручаюсь

Comment: а, ну да, у меня стоит 5.1.0

Comment: @Yaroslav ну как, решили свою проблему?

Comment: Я так понял, что проблема решается путем переустановки компилятора) но меня пока и этот устраивает__)