# Как найти остаток от деления переменной, если она типа double?

Tags: c++, типы-данных, деление

```
double amount;
cin >> amount;
if (amount % 1 == 0)
{...}
```

Вот такой код не работает, поскольку amount в программе имеет тип double, сама ошибка:

> E2140 выражение должно относиться к целочисленному типу или типу
> перечисления без области видимости

По условия задачи, нужно выполнить проверку того, что пользователь ввел число без дробной части в данном конкретном случае и если это так, то уже выполнять код в скобках, а если число дробное, то выполнить уже другое действие.

Comment: См. [`fmod()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod)

Comment: [floor](https://linux.die.net/man/3/floor) проще -- `if (amount == floor(amount) { да, введено целое число ...}`

Comment: Представленные способы чувствительны к вычислениям промежуточных результатов с [повышенной точностью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1146272). Перед тестированием на целочисленность и последующим использованием протестированного значения следует сделать что-то вроде `{volatile double tmp = static_cast<double>(amount); amount = static_cast<double>(tmp);}` или тщательно изучить особенности вычислений чисел с плавающей точкой в конкретном компиляторе. В противном случае, приведённые способы могут давать ошибочные результаты.

Comment: [Пример с `floor`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9e3229cd823efc0), [пример с кастом к `long long`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfaae9d3af830166).

Answer (score 1):

Остаток от деления для вещественных чисел считается функцией [`fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod).

Comment: Зачем забивать гвозди микроскопом? (даже если у ТС есть (очевидно, по незнанию предмета) такое желание)

Comment: @avp, а какие ещё варианты? Кроме чтения строки и парсинга. Диапазон double не очень хочет покрываться целочисленными типами... В принципе, я запостил другой ответ, но не понимаю, чем он лучше.

Comment: @avp, а, тьфу. Увидел коммент. Ответы надо в ответы писать, а не в комменты.

Answer (score 0):

Проверить, что вещественное число целое, можно так:

```
fabs(x) >= 9007199254740992 || (long long)x == x
```

Answer (score -1):

Опреатор остатка от деления **не может** быть использован на не целочисленных типах попробуй такой вариант:

```
if (amount  == (int)amount )
```

Это преобразование типов и можно будет сравнить является ли amount своему же аналогу только целочисленному.

Comment: На некоторых входных данных [работает неверно](https://rextester.com/NEMVD52328).

Comment: Можно пример?Это же обычное приведение к инту, любая вещественная часть отсекается

Comment: @StackITS64, не все значения целые значения double поместятся в int (32 бита со знаком это примерно +-2млрд. (точнее см. в /usr/include/limits.h))